# JdbcTemplate - replace question mark

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a sql query.

```
String sql = "SELECT ? FROM Users WHERE Lastname=?";
```

I use a method queryForList from JDBCTemplate

```
Object [] myparams = {"name", "Doe"};
int [] mytypes = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
List<Map<String,Object>> listOfMaps = jdbc.queryForList(sql, myparams, mytypes);
```

The output is incorrect because there is a problem with the first question mark. I thought the question mark would be replaced by the parameter from myparams array, but it didn't work that way.

Is it possible to do what I want to achieve, but not by manually adding parameter to the string?

Comment: The question mark you can only use for parameter in where statement. Not for columns in select statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the question mark only for the parameters in the where statement.

Comment: Ok, but is there any other way to do what I want to? Which is inserting a string to a query in a way that is safe?

Comment: No, why can't you use "Select *" ?

Comment: Because the query can return a huge list of object, and only some columns might be needed. I don't want to parse the list after the query.

Comment: ok, then you can use perhaps different select queries for the different business cases.

Comment: "can return a huge list of object, and only some columns might be needed. "   <---  Right that is why you have a mapper to get the columns you want.   There is no need to specify it in your query.   And if you do specify it in your query you do not need to dynamically do so.

Comment: "I don't want to parse the list after the query" <---  Not sure I follow.  You understand that a list is created by rows and the SELECT clause defines columns?   So it has no effect on the size of the list.  Only the number of columns returned, and no matter how many columns returned you have a JDBC mapper to give you the fields you want.

Comment: That is not entirely correct: In a lot of databases you can use parameters anywhere a **value** is expected. In most database it is usually also possible to specify a parameter in the select clause to return the value set (but you can't use the parameter to specify the name of a column), but it usually requires one to identify the type of the parameter (eg through an explicit cast).

Comment: @BrianC do you mean RowMapper class?

Answer (score 0):

Neither JDBC nor Spring offer a way to build SQL queries from smaller pieces.

You can try a special pattern to mark the parts you want to replace. Generally it is not good practice ( due to possible sql injection attacks )

```
 String sql = "SELECT ${columns} FROM Users WHERE Lastname=?"
     .replace("${columns}", "name");
```

For this to be secure, you must make sure that `"name"` can't be injected by an attacker. Try to use string constants (`final static String`) or enums. Never accept values from outside (web browser, environment variables) without validating them.